# Delete cookies in java script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

My actual prob is [asp post back issue and html controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428458/asp-post-back-issue-and-html-controls).
i try to solve this in this way.

```
if ($('#rdb1').attr("checked")) {
                document.cookie = $('#rdb1').attr("id");
                check = document.cookie.split(';');
                flag = check[0];

            } else {
                document.cookie = $('#rdb2').attr("id");
                check = document.cookie.split(';');
                flag = check[0];
            }



            if (flag == "rdb1") {
                $('#rdb1').attr("checked", true);
                $('#rdb2').attr("checked", false);


            } if (flag == "rdb2") {
                $('#rdb1').attr("checked", false);
                $('#rdb2').attr("checked", true);
        }
```

its work.But how to  remove cookie i dont know.I search hear and find[javascript - delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie) I don't want a  function.Just want to delete cookies in next button.how to do this?Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you could give this cookie plugin a try https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @elclanrs there is not any method in java script to delete cookies without function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just trigger [that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie) in you button's onclick event..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function del_cookie(name)
{
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
</script>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON OnClick="del_cookie('put name of cookie here');" VALUE="Clear Cookie"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recomend the way you are implementing the cookie, I think you should use name/value pairs. But for the actual implementation you are using, to clear the cookie, you can use:

```
document.cookie = '';
```

Note that  this won't work if you start using name/value pairs because it would only add an empty name/value to your existing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the cookie

And finally, to delete a cookie set its value to null.
Note:- Setting it to e.g. an empty string doesn’t remove it; it just clears the value.

$.cookie("example", null);

or

This is a session cookie and will be destroy when user close his/her browser. We can do it like this:

$.cookie("example", "demo", { expires: -1 });